# Firefox addons with password fields in Ubuntu 18.04 won't open

Tags: firefox, add-on

I'm seeing an issue where Firefox addons with a button in toolbar can't be used if the addon contains text fields for passwords. These same addons work fine on my Windows machine, so I believe the issue is somehow connected to Firefox on Ubuntu.

I have several addons in toolbar, and all of them work fine except for those that require a login. When I click on a broken addon, its window opens briefly then immediately disappears, making it impossible to login.

One of my misbehaving addons is for a password manager. Because this addon is made available through the Firefox sidebar tool, I can use the sidebar to login. Once logged in, the toolbar piece of the addon works just fine.

Addons that require a username and password to log in have interesting behavior. If I click in the username text field, I can add text, but the moment I click in the password field, the window closes. I have other addons that have fields for text entry, but none of those fields asks for a password, and they work fine.

To address this problem, I've tried purging Firefox and deleting all config files. I reinstalled only one addon, one of the misbehaving ones, and it still exhibits the same problem.

I'm completely stumped on troubleshooting steps. Where should I look to find more information about what could be the source of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with Ubuntu 18.04's ibus package implementation. https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2002

It seems there is nothing users can do to resolve this issue but wait.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by installing the Snap version of Firefox. Here are the steps that I did:

1. Remove the current version installed,

   ```
   sudo apt-get uninstall firefox
   ```
2. Install the Snap version

   ```
   sudo snap install firefox
   ```

Try installing an addon that requires you to log-in. In my case, that's LastPass. Working now.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me. I just type the password on another field then drag the text to password field (lol). Well, it's not a secure way because anyone can see your password, but if you are alone or doesn't mind your account password being seen, you can try it.