# Password field problem - Firefox

Tags: firefox, password

I'm new to ubuntu and have just installed ubuntu 18.04 and I'm running Firefox which came bundled in the package.

I have a problem were I can't enter a password into the password field on certain websites, example: [www.clickstay.com](https://www.clickstay.com)

I have just spent an hour trawling through various suggestions which all sound a bit scary for a new user like installing a deb file suggestion on github and bugzilla. I also tried installing a snap version of firefox.

**The only solution that worked** was [changing the input source in "Language and region" from Ibus to XIM](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2002#issuecomment-411218148).

...but is this the best solution? Or can anybody suggest an Ubuntu recommended fix from a safe Ubuntu software package source?

Comment: It's probably a Firefox bug. Firefox for Linux is different to that for Windows, but I've never had an issue logging on to any website in Linux with FF until you pointed this one out. I see you can log on fine through Facebook though, so use that, or try another browser like Chrome.

Comment: After installing Ubuntu, did you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`? This looks like a bug reported back in April'18 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033637/)

Comment: Thanks Kulfy I just run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, it did not unfortunately solve the problem. Also I really don't want to use chrome.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Interesting, I just tested on my system here running 18.04.1 and it works fine without issue typing into the password field like the site you have listed.  Mine is a clean install of 18.04 running just the Firefox that comes from the installation.  However, what they are saying about the `snap` version is first remove the Firefox already there `sudo apt remove firefox` then install the snap version instead `snap install firefox` and do all this from a terminal window.

Comment: @PaulBenson There's currently a bug in Firefox on Ubuntu that prevents an extension from displaying a password field in its popup.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a follow up, and solution for anyone looking:

Uninstalling Firefox that came with the installation bundle using the terminal command

> sudo apt remove firefox

and then installing the snap version using command

> snap install firefox

has fixed the problem I was having.

Many thanks to all who replied

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 in May 2020: Pages containing a password field were loading really slow wiht 100% CPU usage for several seconds until the cursor reapeared in the password field.

The reason was the addon for "Grammarly" which worked fine in 19.10.
I disabled the addon and everything runs smoothe again